# Multiple definition of main()

Tags: c, header

I have three files: `cshot.c`, containing `main()`, `screenshot.h` header, and it's implementation `screenshot.c`.

cshot.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include "screenshot.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{ ... }
```

screenshot.h

```
#ifndef SCREENSHOT_H
#define SCREENSHOT_H
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

extern char *err_log;

int take_screenshot(char *path);
#endif
```

screenshot.c

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include "screenshot.h"

int
take_screenshot(char *path)
{ ... }
```

Trying to compile this resulting the following:

```
obj/screenshot.o: in function `main': ... multiple definition of `main';
multiple definition of `argp_program_bug_address'; obj/cshot.o:/usr/include/argp.h:401: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: obj/screenshot.o:/usr/include/argp.h:385: multiple definition of `argp_program_version'; obj/cshot.o:/usr/include/argp.h:385: first defined here
```

Edit, here's Makefile

```
TARGET = cshot
CC = gcc

SRC_PATH = src/
OBJ_PATH = obj/

SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)*.c)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)%.c, $(OBJ_PATH)%.o, $(SRC))

FLAGS = -Wall -g -O3
LINK = -lX11

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LINK) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET)

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $(LINK) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm  $(OBJ_PATH)*.o
    rm $(TARGET)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you build your program? Please show  command line and related files, e.g. Makefile if you use make.

Comment: Sounds like you've included source inadvertently, or included the same `.c` file twice somehow.

Comment: It's a linking error. I am assuming you are making two object files, one with just `cshot.c` and one with both `cshot.c` *and* `screenshot.c`. Then linking both into an executable would throw an error.

Comment: $(OBJ): $(SRC) looks very suspicious. Do all of your object files depend on all of your source files? Maybe you meant something like ".c.o". If you did, there is probably already an implicit rule for that, and you can delete that statement.

Comment: And you don't want $(LINK) in the compilation stage. Just for the final link. (It's probably harmless, but very confusing.) Anyway, make should log which commands it carries out. If you still can't make it work, add that to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Makefile `$(OBJ): $(SRC)` expands to:

```
obj/cshot.o obj/screenshot.o: src/cshot.c src/screenshot.c
```

`$<` variable expands to first prerequisite, in this case it is always `src/cshot.c`.

For `obj/schot.o` build command looks correct:

```
gcc -c -Wall -g -O3 -lX11 src/cshot.c -o obj/cshot.o
```

but for `obj/screenshot.o` it is:

```
gcc -c -Wall -g -O3 -lX11 src/cshot.c -o obj/screenshot.o
```

Thus both `cshot.o` and `screenshot.o` are object files compiled from the same `cshot.c` and contain `main()`.

Receipt for compilation can be like this:

```
$(OBJ_PATH)%.o: $(SRC_PATH)%.c
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You don't need linker flags for compilation. Conventional name for compiler flags is `CFLAGS`, for linker flags it is `LDFLAGS`.
Also you can use built-in variables for compilation and cleanup:

```
TARGET = cshot
CC = gcc

SRC_PATH = src/
OBJ_PATH = obj/

SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)*.c)
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)%.c, $(OBJ_PATH)%.o, $(SRC))

CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O3
LDFLAGS = -lX11

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(LINK.c) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_PATH)%.o: $(SRC_PATH)%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ_PATH)*.o $(TARGET)
```

Output:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -g -O3   -c -o obj/cshot.o src/cshot.c
gcc -Wall -g -O3   -c -o obj/screenshot.o src/screenshot.c
gcc -Wall -g -O3  -lX11  obj/cshot.o obj/screenshot.o -o cshot
$ make clean
rm -f obj/*.o cshot
```